# Fetching a value only if true in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to create a Ticket raising system, where the admin creates a ticket and it is stored in a collection named Tickets, and the name of the ticket is stored in a subcollection named 'tickets' in another collection named 'student' as a boolean value .

Whenever the student raises a ticket the value of that specific ticket is set to true, which can be later fetched on the admin side to check who are the students that have raised the said ticket.

I had an issue with fetching the students who had raised it by sorting it by true . The name of the ticket is stored in a field name 'content'   in both the collections.

I am using Next.Js 14,TS and Firebase

The fetching logic :

```
const ticketsRef = collection(db, "student", studentId, "tickets");
        const ticketsSnapshot = await getDocs(ticketsRef);

        ticketsSnapshot.forEach((ticketDoc) => {
          const ticketName = ticketDoc.id;
          const ticketData = ticketDoc.data();
          console.log("ticketdata:", ticketData);

          // Check if content field exists and its value for the specific ticketName is true
          const hasTicket =
            ticketData &&
            typeof ticketData.content === "object" &&
            ticketData.content &&
            ticketData.content[ticketName] === true;

          // If 'content' is still undefined, provide a default value
          const contentOrDefault = ticketData.content || {};

          console.log("ticketData:", ticketData);
          console.log("ticketName:", ticketName);
          console.log("Content:", ticketData.content);

          console.log(
            `Student ID: ${studentId}, Ticket Name: ${ticketName}, Has Ticket: ${hasTicket}`
          );

          if (hasTicket) {
            raisedTickets.content = true; // Set content to true if any ticket is raised
          }
        });

        console.log(
          `Student ID: ${studentId}, Number of Tickets: ${
            raisedTickets.content ? 1 : 0
          }`
        );
        studentsDetailsArray.push(raisedTickets);
      });

      if (studentsDetailsArray.length > 0) {
        console.log("Students Data Loaded", studentsDetailsArray);
        setStudents(studentsDetailsArray);
      } else {
        console.log("No Students Found");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error fetching students", error);
    }
```

In the console.log I set up I get the hasTickets as undefined .
Can anybody help me with this or suggest a better logic to do the same

It should show the count of the students who have raised it by showing the number of students who have the value as true

```
  ticketData.content[ticketName] === true;
  
          console.log(`Student ID: ${studentId}, Ticket Name: ${ticketName}, Has Ticket: ${hasTicket}`);
```

this console.log fetches and shows the content: [true/false] but the hasTickets fails to count the number of students who have it as true

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: ok i have changed it. Can you check it again now ? Thanks